# Is it possible for a keypair to import a certificate without a CSR file?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have obtained a free Open Source Developer certificate (with Code Signing as only usage) from [Certum](https://sklep.unizeto.pl/certum.php?language=en) in reply to a web form instead of a regular CSR file. The Certificate has no installation issues on Windows and forms a trusted chain along with the corresponding intermediate and root CA certificates in any keystore management tool I have tried. No problems so far.

Nevertheless, besides the bright side of becoming somewhat acquainted with the subject after frustrating studying it for several days (my only purpose was to sign jar files for [my online solfège school](http://doremitutor.com/theory/tutor.php)), I haven't been able to import the certificate to any keypair on neither toolkey, KeyStore Explorer, CERTivity, nor OpenSSL, because the public keys don't match, (I think) obviously.

I (probably mis)understand that the public key from a requesting keypair is conveyed to the CA by the CSR file and included back in the certificate reply, but in my case there is no CSR file.

I plainly admit my ignorance, and would just like to know:

1. If is it even possible (with all security risks involved) the procedure of tailoring a keypair to match an existing such a certificate (an Openssl command, perhaps), and
2. if, as I'm afraid of, the answer is no, what is such a "CSR-file-orphan" certificate useful for?

Any enlightment will be greatly appreciated.

Jesús Díaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certum probably have created the CSR for you if you didn't submit one.
In that case, a (public-private) key pair would have been installed on your computer.
You will probably have to export the key pair from Windows keystore to a file so that you can import it to another keystore.

[guide from microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-vista/import-or-export-certificates-and-private-keys)

[with screenshots](http://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html)

[another way](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1217629)

To answer your questions:

1. since the certificate has been created, you won't be able to create a key pair for it.
2. it is actually not a CSR orphan certificate

You might want to make another request from Certum and inform them that you would like to provide a CSR

Comment: Hi, authcate! Thanks for your help. The problem is through now.
Here is the catch up for the case: I submitted the for from Google Chrome generating the CSR in Chrome's keystore and obviously sending from that browser.
As I used IE to open my email and subsequently the Certum's response download page, I find myself unabled to install my brand new crtificate.

Comment: Sorry, my novice condition is showing up by my splitting my comment. Certum's staff kindly helped me by letting me know that I should import the certificate from Chrome, and the case was closed. I hope this can save someone some work. Again, thank you very much. I apologize for my handling of the comment form.